# Add plots to jupyter console without creating a new viewer on Linux

Tags: jupyter, ipython, jupyter-console, x-dwm

I am running jupyter-console on the command line

```
jupyter console
```

This essentially starts IPython on the command line as desired. When I use matplotplib. E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.arange(0, 10)
plt.plot(a, np.cos(a))
```

it shows the plot in Xviewer (I am on Linux using DWM). However, every time I create a plot a new Xviewer session is started. The new plots are also visible in the already existing Xviewer sessions where I can scroll through all the plots I have made. How do I ensure I only have one Xviewer session running? Is this something that can be set in jupyter-console or is this an operating system setting?